# Access HDFS from a WebApplication

Tags: asp.net, .net, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I have HDFS running in a cluster of two system. Now I would like to create a Web Application in Dot Net that should try to access this HDFS from anywhere and perform the tasks. Is this possible ? If so , Can anyone please brief me with the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [WebHDFS Rest API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html).

Comment: I have gone through the link but still I am bit confused . So My requirement is I must be able to hit  the HDFS( which would be running in separate systems ) from any place via the internet/intranet . Is this possible with WebHdfs and can u just brief about it .

Comment: I just got some idea , I refered http://hortonworks.com/blog/webhdfs-%E2%80%93-http-rest-access-to-hdfs/. Shall i follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535046/how-to-authenticate-webhdfs-with-c-sharp this link where they are trying to download and upload data and Is there any settings i need to before following the same .

Comment: Is it possible to run HDFSFindTool Command via WebHDFS  . The command is " hadoop jar /usr/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-*-job.jar \
org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool -find \
hdfs:///user/$USER/solrloadtest/twitter/tweets -type f -name \
'sample-statuses*.gz' -mmin -60 -size -1000000000c -size +1000000c ".